# Mysql connectivity from POcket pc application using .netcf 2.0

Tags: mysql, database, compact-framework, pocketpc, database-connectivity

We are developing an order taking system in PDA using C# in .netcf 2.0. So we are having mysql server as our back end. Is that the web service is the only way to  connect mysql with PDA? Or is any other methods available..?

Answer (score 1):

There is a .netcf connector on MySql web site available for download.
I recommend to use version 5.2.7 and not to forget to put "pooling=false" into the connection string, otherwise connection will fail with exception "MissingManifestResourceException" .

Connection string example:
"Persist Security Info=False;database=DATABASE_NAME;server=SERVER_IP_ADDRESS;user id=USERNAME_TO_LOGON;Password=PASSWORD;**pooling=false**"

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is a Data Provider for MySQL in Compact Framework.

I recommend that you read the [Mobile Application Architecture Guide](http://blogs.msdn.com/jmeier/archive/2008/11/24/mobile-application-architecture-pocket-guide.aspx), especially the Data Layer chapter to see what your options are.